# inline-r exception when installing with cabal

Tags: r, haskell, inline

I installed H and inline-r with full. I did not use sandbox. Apparently everything installed, but when I run some script the following error occurs:

```
• Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
    R: readCreateProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)
  Code: Language.Haskell.TH.Quote.quoteExp
          r " matrix(xs_hs,ncol = 2) "
• In the quasi-quotation: [r| matrix(xs_hs,ncol = 2) |]
```

The code is the example of the official website: https://tweag.github.io/HaskellR/

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import H.Prelude as H
import Language.R.QQ

import System.Random

main = H.withEmbeddedR defaultConfig $ do
  H.runRegion $ do
    -- Put any complex model here
    std <- io $ newStdGen
    let (xs::[Double]) = take 100 $ randoms std
    d  <- [r| matrix(xs_hs,ncol = 2) |]
    rv <- [r| clusters <- kmeans(d_hs, 2) |]
    [r| par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1));
        plot(d_hs, col = rv_hs$cluster, pch = 20
            , cex = 3, xlab = "x", ylab = "y");
        points(rv_hs$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4);
      |]
    return ()
```

somebody salve me!!

Comment: rectifying: I installed H and inline-r with cabal.

Comment: Do you have `R` installed?

Comment: `R` doesn't seem to be installed. I recommend using `nix` with `stack build --nix` which will automatically install all dependencies that you need, including system ones. See https://tweag.github.io/HaskellR/docs/build-and-install.html

Comment: Yes. Version R-3.4.2. The cabal.config set with: extra-include-dirs:
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\mingw\include
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\include
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\mingw\lib
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64
extra-prog-path: C:\Users\Rodolpho Morethson\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\msys\usr\bin
extra-prog-path: C:\Users\Rodolpho Morethson\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\msys\usr\bin

Comment: I want a globally installing inline-r. The packages that I use are: yesod , inline-r and H.

Comment: Is there some way installing H and inline-r globally with stack?

Comment: I instaled using: stack build H --extra-lib-dirs=C:\R\bin\i386 --extra-include-dirs=C:\R\include. Same error!!